# How can I persist data onto the Netduino?

Tags: .net-micro-framework, netduino

Mainly, I want to persist data onto the onboard Netduino memory (if there is any?) without hooking anything else up.

The idea is that I either read the data back in the next time the Netduino is plugged in (for settings), or read the data when it's plugged into a computer (for analytical data). Specifically data from sensors like temperature, ambient light, GPS Position, xyz orientation, etc.

I know there is the Netduino Plus, which has a MicroSD slot to store data via `System.IO`, but I have a regular Netduino :(

Answer (score 2):

SkippyFire, you can add an SD card using the v4.1.1 firmware and an expansion shield.  The Adafruit MicroSD expansion card also works.

There is a feature within .NET Micro Framework called "ExtendedWeakReferences" which can be used if you recompile the firmware and enable it--but I'd highly recommend using MicroSD instead.  Simpler, standard, and powerful.

Chris

Comment: Hmmm... is "ExtendedWeakReferences" dangerous?  I'm trying to find the cheapest possible way to store (any) data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Netduino, but most PIC microprocessors have self-writeable flash memory. Some of them even have a small amount of on board EEPROM ~1kB. Both types of memory are non-volatile and will provide you with a way to store data between power-ups.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN provides a [extendedweakreferences sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc561925.aspx)
and I believe this requires to write and read to flash memory, which I guess the Netduino has.

So essentially the extendedweakreferences class is just a way of letting you use flash memory.
In relation to your question is it safe? Yes it provides a way of encapsulating the read/write process, although it may not be safe for whatever data was already on the flash memory in the same location.